# Create hyperlink to Google Voice phone number

Tags: google-voice

I want to add some hyperlinks to phone numbers on a web page, and I'm wondering if it's possible to do this using Google Voice. Is there any way to create a hyperlink to a Google Voice phone number (so that clicking the hyperlink would allow a user to call a specific phone number using Google Voice)?

Comment: There is a relevant search results page for this question, but I haven't found any answers yet. https://www.google.com/?&q=(hyperlink|URL)%20to%20google%20voice%20number#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=(hyperlink%7CURL)+to+google+voice+number&oq=(hyperlink%7CURL)+to+google+voice+number&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.0.2416.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c..2.hp.FILyg_USdMI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41867550,d.dmQ&fp=38c99f73bc28ba74&biw=1366&bih=630

Comment: This won't achieve YOUR goal, but others will appreciate this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571924/470749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a hyperlink, but you can add a voicemail widget to your website.

> [About voicemail widgets](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115128)
>
> You can allow others to call you from your website or blog by adding a voicemail widget to it. Visitors to the website can click the widget, enter their phone number, and Google Voice will call them and connect the call to your Google number. Here's how you can set up a voicemail widget:
>
> 1. Go to the gear icon at the top right of the page.
> 2. Go to Voice settings.
> 3. Click the Voicemail Widgets tab.
> 4. Click the Add a new Voicemail Widget link.
> 5. Select the appropriate settings for your widget.
> 6. Click the Save Changes. Then, copy and paste the code in the 'Embed' field into your webpage, your blog, your auction or networking site, or anywhere you want.
>
> You can customize each of your voicemail widgets. Here are the options:
>
> - Specific settings (so that callers go to voicemail or ring only certain phones)
> - Specific greetings
> - Turning call screening on and off

Comment: On which page should I click the gear icon? On the linked page, I clicked the gear icon, and nothing was displayed in the drop-down menu.

Comment: You have to be logged in to Google Voice and looking at your inbox.